# Data Cache (XCache, APC, memcached, etc) on shared hosting / privacy considerations

Tags: hosting, cache, alternative-php-cache, xcache

I have one question. How appropriate is to use on shared hosting a cache system for data?

I mean as far as I know the data is written in a shared data cache (not private for each user) across all users. And on a busy server other users will have access to my cached data. And the situation can get even worse, by mistake diff users may have same application and so the data may get overwrite by other user, etc.

So, I am wrong or a data cache is not recommended for shared environments because of privacy issue?

Comment: Typically setting up an in-memory cache system requires physical access to the server itself, which in a shared environment you never get.  Regardless, you have not provided enough background about how your environment is setup, who the host is, and what you are trying to achieve for anyone to provide an answer to you.  Try to flesh out your question a bit more.